# Extending a supermapped class in Symfony2 does not add the columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am extending FOSAuthServerBundle and it has entities that are supermapped class and I need to extend them. Let's take one, **AccessToken**. When I extend **AccessToken**, I need all of its parent properties to be mapped in the database, such as `$expiresAt` and `$scope` but currently, they are not. Clearly, there is something I don't understand or am doing wrong.

Here's what I have in my own AccessToken yml:

```
OSC\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToOne:
        client:
            targetEntity: Client

        user:
            targetEntity: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Here's my Accesstoken php file:

```
<?php

namespace OSC\OAuthServerBundle\Entity;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\ClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


class AccessToken extends BaseAccessToken
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    protected $client;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

When I run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force, the only fields that I have in my database are **id**, **user_id** and **client_id**. But I also need **expiresAt** and **scope**...

**Here's what I have verified:**

- I am properly extending the FOSAuthServerBundle:

  ```
  namespace OSC\OAuthServerBundle;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

  class OSCOAuthServerBundle extends Bundle
  {
      public function getParent()
      {
          return 'FOSOAuthServerBundle';
      }
  }
  ```
- The FOSOAuthServerBundle and OSCOAuthServerBundle are in the list of doctrine mappings in config.yml
- I cleared the cache.

Is it normal that the fields are not mapped automatically ? Do I have to rewrite them all in the yml config? If yes, in my head, it defeats the purpose of a mapped superclass. Maybe I have to write in the yml that it inherits from a mapped superclass ?

**Edit 1** : Maybe this does not work since the base class Token is not abstract ?

**Solution**:

I had to point to Entity and not Model as a tutorial was telling me. This is so since in the ORM mapping in the bundle files, the mapping is done for the entity and not the model !

```
<?php

namespace OSC\OAuthServerBundle\Entity;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken; //Entity here not model !
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\ClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


class AccessToken extends BaseAccessToken
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to extend this class : `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken` instead of this one `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\AccessToken` ?

You don't have to declare your properties twice (in super and sub class).
Do not redeclare `$id`, `$client` and `$user`

Comment: I just tried, I deleted the table and recreated it but it didn't work! Thanks though.

Comment: Why do you declare $id, $client & $user in your class as the superclass already do it ? Look the Doctrine example : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses. Only the Superclass has $mapped1 & $mapped2 declaration. Superclass fields are "protected" you can use them in the sub class, without declare them again.

Comment: Doctrine declared them automatically. But even if I remove them, I still have only those 3 in my database table.

Comment: Ok, So I had to removed them and also use Entity and not Model !

Comment: ok, I edit my answer, I think the double declaration was the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank you and also, just in case other people see it, it has to be replaced with FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken. If you can change in your answer that would be great.